# problem with nn.ModuleDict ('method' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, oop, pytorch, typeerror

I am trying to use `nn.ModuleDict` following this [documentation page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleDict.html):

I have this PyTorch network:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        modules = {}
        modules["layer1"] = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=2)
        self.modules = nn.ModuleDict(modules)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.modules["layer1"](x)
```

when I use the forward method, I get the following error:

> 'method' object is not subscriptable

when I change the forward method to:

```
  def forward(self, x):
        x = self.modules()["layer1"](x)
```

I get the following error:

> **TypeError**: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `"modules"` is already used by `nn.Module`. The property is used to retrieve all modules of the model: see [`nn.Module.modules`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.modules). You need to use another property name.

For example:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        modules = {}
        modules["layer1"] = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 
            kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=2)
        self.layers = nn.ModuleDict(modules)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layers["layer1"](x)
        return x
```